# How to update ubuntu 12.04 through squid proxy server at my university ??

Tags: linux, networking

I wish to update the local package index with the latest changes made in repositories and am using following command :

```
     sudo apt-get update
```

On executing this command I get several error messages such as one below :

```
  W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  407  Proxy Authentication Required
```

What i did to in order to try resolving this issue is the following :

Open terminal and the file

```
/etc/bash.bashrsc

sudo gedit /etc/bash.bashrc
```

and add at the bottom of the file these 2 lines :

```
export http_proxy=http://user:password@host:port/
export ftp_proxy=http://user:pass@host:port/
```

However it is still not working for me and am getting the same error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is another stackexchange site for ubuntu questions: http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Might be helpful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/88976/407-proxy-authentication-required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For apt-get to work

```
 sudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

And then add

```
    Acquire::http::Proxy "http://username:password@proxyhost:port/";
```

The syntax should be strictly followed

This may fail if our password or possibly username (i don't know) has '@' in it.

We can add proxy for other protocols like ftp etc. also there..